# WebSockets/Long-Polling on ASP.NET - Shared Host?

Tags: asp.net, websocket, hosting, long-polling

I am building a website that will be handling many persistent connections - either through long polling or WebSockets (if I get a host that has IIS8). My question is, are either of these viable on a shared host? Or do I need a true dedicated server?

I understand that long-polling will require me to do some custom configuration on the maximum number of requests handled by the server.. so it seems like this is not an option on a shared host. What about WebSockets? And, will either of these work with "virtual" or "cloud" hosting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want or need to use a shared host then you could offload the handling of the persistent connections to a [realtime web hosted service](http://www.leggetter.co.uk/real-time-web-technologies-guide#hosted-services). I work for one such company, [Pusher](http://pusher.com), but there are a few others out there too (all linked to from the guide above).

Answer (score 0):

These techniques will work with any kind of hosting, but you will exceed the resource limit of shared hosting quite fast. So I'd recommend starting with a VPS at least.